# List all the subroutine names in perl program

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am using more modules in my perl program.
example:

```
use File::copy;
```

so likewise File module contains Basename, Path, stat and etc..
i want to list all the subroutine(function) names which is in File Package module.

In python has dir(modulename)
It list all the function that used in that module....
example:
#!/usr/bin/python

```
# Import built-in module math
import math

content = dir(math)

print content
```

Like python tell any code for in perl

Comment: Does this help you?: [What's the best way to discover all subroutines a Perl module has?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607282/whats-the-best-way-to-discover-all-subroutines-a-perl-module-has)

Comment: See [`Devel::Examine::Subs`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Examine::Subs)

Comment: Re "so likewise File module contains Basename, Path, stat". No, it doesn't There is no File module, and there is no relationship between the File::Basename and File::Path modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to look at the contents of a namespace in perl, you can use `%modulename::`.

For `main` that's either `%main::` or `%::`.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

sub fish {};
sub carrot {};

print "Stuff defined in Dumper:\n"; 
print Dumper \%Data::Dumper::;

print "Stuff defined:\n";
print Dumper \%::;
```

That covers a load of stuff though - including pragmas. But you can check for e.g. subroutines by simply testing it for being a code reference.

```
foreach my $thing ( keys %:: ) {
   if ( defined &$thing ) { 
        print "sub $thing\n";
   }
}
```

And with reference to the above sample, this prints:

```
sub Dumper
sub carrot
sub fish
```

So with reference to your original question:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use File::Copy;

print "File::Copy has subs of:\n";
foreach my $thing ( keys %File::Copy:: ) {
   if ( defined &$thing ) { 
        print "sub $thing\n";
   }
}
```

Unfortunately you can't do the same thing with the whole `File::` namespace, because there's a whole bunch of different modules that *could* be installed/loaded, but might not be.

You'd have to use e.g. CPAN to check that -

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
i /^File::/
```

Which will list you around 717 modules that are grouped into the `File::` tree.

You could look this up on [`CPAN`](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=File%3A%3A&mode=module). Or if you're just after the core modules, then some variant of using `Module::CoreList` might do what you want.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Module::CoreList;

foreach my $module ( Module::CoreList->find_modules(qr/^File::/) ) {
    if ( eval { require $module =~ s|::|/|gr . ".pm" } ) {
        print "Module: $module contains\n";
        my $key_str = "\%$module\:\:";

        my %stuff = eval $key_str;
        foreach my $thing ( sort keys %stuff ) {
            my $full_sub_path = "$module::$thing";
            if ( eval {"defined &$full_sub_path"} ) {
                if ( defined &$thing ) {
                    print "$thing <- $full_sub_path imported by default\n";
                }
                else {
                    print "\t$full_sub_path might be loadable\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        print "Module: $module couldn't be loaded\n";
    }
}
```

It's a bit messy because you have to `eval` various bits of it to test if a module is in fact present and loadable at runtime. Oddly enough, `File::Spec::VMS` wasn't present on my `Win32` system. Can't think why.... :).

Should note - just because you *could* import a sub from a module (that isn't exported by default) doesn't make it a good idea. By convention, any sub prefixed with an `_` is not supposed to be used externally, etc.

Comment: You obviously need some lunch soon. :)

Comment: FEED ME SEYMOUR! (yes, it is coming up to lunchtime).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sobrique

Answer (score 2):

My [Devel::Examine::Subs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Examine::Subs) module can do this, plus much more. Note that whether it's a method or function is irrelevant, it'll catch both. It works purely on subroutines as found with [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/~mithaldu/PPI-1.220/lib/PPI.pm).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Devel::Examine::Subs;

my $des = Devel::Examine::Subs->new;

my $subs = $des->module(module => 'File::Copy');

for (@$subs){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Output:

```
_move
move
syscopy
carp
mv
_eq
_catname
cp
copy
croak
```

Or a file/full directory. For all Perl files in a directory (recursively), just pass the dir to `file` param without a file at the end of the path:

```
my $des = Devel::Examine::Subs->new(file => '/path/to/file.pm');

my $subs = $des->all;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print it use the Data::Dumper module and the following method, CGI used as an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $object = CGI->new();

{
    no strict 'refs';
    print "Instance METHOD IS  " . Dumper( \%{ref ($object)."::" }) ;
}
```

Also note, it's File::Copy, not File::copy.

Comment: File::Copy is not object oriented and OP is asking for finding subroutines.  However, to get all _methods_ of a _class_ (which is, granted, a package/namespace) it makes a lot more sense to use [Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer), which has that built in. `p $object` will give a nice list of all the methods and attributes it has.

Comment: I really like the look of the `Data::Printer` module @simbabque... I can see numerous benefits to it over others for specific troubleshooting.